# Using rank-nullity for rankA + rank(adj(A)) = n iff col(adj(A)) = nullA

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, dimension-theory-algebra

Let A be an $n \times n$ matrix. Show that $A$ is not invertible and $\text{rank } A + \text{rank}(\text{adj}(A)) = n$ if and only if $\text{col}(\text{adj}(A)) = \text{null } A$.

The rank-nullity states that $\text{rank }A + \text{nullity} = n$, so we could assume $\text{nullity} = \text{rank}(\text{adj}(A))$ right? Then you can derive $\text{rank}(\text{adj}(A) = \text{dim}(\text{col}(\text{adj}(A)))$ given that $\text{rank}(A) = \text{dim}(\text{col}(A)$. Where can I go from there?

Comment: Mathematics Stack Exchange uses MathJax to render equations. Try and learn the basics, it makes your equations much easier to read and they also look more pleasant. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a link to a basic tutorial. It's easy when you get the hang of it!

Answer (score 0):

To finish the 'only if' part: since $A\cdot {\rm adj}(A)=\det(A)\cdot I=0$, each column of ${\rm adj}(A)$ is in the nullspace $\ker(A)$, so ${\rm col}({\rm adj}(A)) \subseteq \ker(A)$.

For the 'if' part, we get $A\cdot{\rm adj}(A)=0$, so $A$ is not invertible, and the dimension calculation you made yields
$$n={\rm rank}(A)+{\rm null}(A)={\rm rank}(A) +{\rm rank}({\rm adj}(A))$$

Comment: I don't think you can conclude directly from $A\cdot\operatorname{adj}(A) = 0$ that $A$ is not invertible; concluding directly seems to me to require that $\operatorname{adj}(A) \ne 0$, but we *can* have $\operatorname{adj}(A) = 0$.